# Item "is in use by another application". How can I find out which one?

Tags: finder, macos

In Finder the file `VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool` is greyed out.

[image]

I want to delete this file, but I'm prompted by a message that the file is currently in use:

[image]

Currently, I have no clue what is the cause of this. Therefore I want to know what other application is using it. How do I find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is usually a copy job that unexpectedly died or some process that has an open file handle on that file. You can check which process opened which files with `lsof | grep "filename"`. This will not necessarily yield a result. If the issue isn't resolved after a logout or even a restart you still can continue at that dialog and remove the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small application dedicated to this problem: [What's keeping me](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/products/wkm/wkm.html)

This provides a nice UI interface to information typically shown by the `lsof` command line tool.

You can use the UI to search for the name of the, `VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool`, and it will show you the process(es) that are accessing the file and offer you the ability to kill them from the UI.

Comment: What does it do? Answers should be understandable without the link which is only for detail or in this case the download. As for downloads some explanation should be given else you have to expect it to be a virus etc